# node.js - how to get the OS platforms user data folder

Tags: node.js

I am looking for a way to get the userdata folder using Node.js, that will work on both Windows and macOS.

The Node.js instance would be running on the user's machine.

I need something that returns the following:

- `C:\Documents and Settings\JohnD\Application Data` *(Windows XP)*
- `C:\Users\JohnD\AppData\Roaming` *(Windows Vista and Up)*
- `/Users/JohnD/Library/Preferences` *(macOS)*

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check user environment which is stored in [**process.env**](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#process_process_env)

Also, take a look at [**process.platform**](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#process_process_platform)

To be specific:

```
% node                                                                                                                                 
> console.log(process.env.HOME)
/Users/miktam
> console.log(process.platform)
darwin
```

Having this information, you will be able to achieve what you need.

Comment: This does not answer the question. This does not work on Windows, the home directory on Windows is either HOMEPATH or USERPROFILE. The paths asked by the questioner are also the local application path not the home directory.

Answer (score 183):

Try the following:

```
process.env.APPDATA || (process.platform == 'darwin' ? process.env.HOME + '/Library/Preferences' : process.env.HOME + "/.local/share")
```

The expected result is:

OS X - '/Users/*user*/Library/Preferences'

Windows 8 - 'C:\Users\*user*\AppData\Roaming'

Windows XP - 'C:\Documents and Settings\*user*\Application Data'

Linux - '/home/*user*/.local/share'

Comment: This is a much better solution than the accepted answer.

Comment: on my linux box /var/local needs sudo permission. Shouldn't this be somewhere that doesn't require sudo?

Comment: It is really dependent on the type of app you are making. If you are running a shared config between all users you may wish to create a folder with permissions to write on installation, alternatively you could move to the users Home directory (process.env.HOME). However, the OSX link should probably be /Library/Application Support/ so they are all common application paths rather than the OSX link pointing to the users preferences.

Comment: It should be Library/Preferences not Library/Preference, right? I made an edit

Comment: On Linux, it should probably be `process.env.HOME + ".local/share"` or simply `process.env.HOME` with an application `.dotfile`.

Comment: From here, you can likely tailor it to whatever suits your needs for your particular application.

Comment: Add a slash before "/Library/Preferences"

Comment: yuck gives back `/var/local` in linux.  In 2019 Sindresorhus the demi-god solves nearly all basic questions -- correctly across OS too.  https://github.com/sindresorhus/env-paths.    Tip: check here b4 asking any basic JS question on SO.  https://npms.io/search?q=author%3Asindresorhus

Comment: @DKebler thanks for the tip; what a terrific set of libraries. You should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/home/$USER/.config` on Linux?

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk I think you need to tailor it to your own needs. I believe ~/.config is for config and ~/.local/share is for user data files. So it really depends on what you are storing. There was strong support for ~/.local/share and I'm unsure which is more appropriate so I'm going to leave it as is for now

Comment: @Luke Most of the apps on my Linux desktop write to .config (i.e. Chrome), fewer (but plenty) write directly to /home with a dot before the dir name (i.e. /home/user/.mozilla), while very few (almost none) write to .local/share

Comment: I was looking for `process.env.LocalAppData`, it also exists (and case doesn't seem to matter)