# JS get AppData/Local/Packages/<MyApp> path

Tags: javascript, path, appdata

I have a UWP app that uses WebView to display my web content.
Installing my app on windows creates
`C:/Users/[USER_NAME]/AppData/Local/Packages/[MY_APP_NAME]/[SOME_FOLDER]`

Is there any way in js to retrieve the path to this folder? I don't want to hardcode it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Although not a complete solution this here might help set you on your way a-lot!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19276432/9700357

Comment: Both options mentioned in that answer log empty strings by me.